# Calculation going wrong due to JOIN issue

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Table -**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| ID | Client_Id | Driver_Id | City_Id |       Status        | Request_at |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |        10 |       1 | completed           | 2013-10-01 |
|  2 |         2 |        11 |       1 | cancelled_by_driver | 2013-10-01 |
|  3 |         3 |        12 |       6 | completed           | 2013-10-01 |
|  4 |         4 |        13 |       6 | cancelled_by_client | 2013-10-01 |
|  5 |         1 |        10 |       1 | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
|  6 |         2 |        11 |       6 | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
|  7 |         3 |        12 |       6 | completed           | 2013-10-02 |
|  8 |         2 |        12 |      12 | completed           | 2013-10-03 |
|  9 |         3 |        10 |      12 | completed           | 2013-10-03 |
| 10 |         4 |        13 |      12 | cancelled_by_driver | 2013-10-03 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

**My attempt -**

```
WITH src 
     AS (SELECT Count(status) AS Denom, 
                request_at 
         FROM   trips 
         WHERE  status = 'completed' 
         GROUP  BY request_at), 
     src2 
     AS (SELECT Count(status) AS Num, 
                request_at 
         FROM   trips 
         WHERE  status <> 'completed' 
         GROUP  BY request_at) 
SELECT Cast(Count(num) AS FLOAT)/Cast(Count(Denom) AS FLOAT) AS cancel_rate, 
       trips.request_at 
FROM   src, 
       src2, 
       trips 
GROUP  BY trips.request_at;
```

I am trying to find the cancellation rate per day but it is clearing wrong **(MY OUTPUT)**-

```
+-------------+------------+
| cancel_rate | request_at |
+-------------+------------+
|          24 | 2013-10-01 |
|          18 | 2013-10-02 |
|          18 | 2013-10-03 |
+-------------+------------+
```

The cancellation rate for 2013-10-01 should be **0.5** and not 24. Similarly for other dates it should be different.

I know the problem lies with this part but I do not know what is the correct way or how to approach it

```
SELECT Cast(Count(num) AS FLOAT)/Cast(Count(Denom) AS FLOAT) AS cancel_rate, 
       trips.request_at 
FROM   src, 
       src2, 
       trips
```

Is there any way to put in more than 1 select statement in `With NAME as ()` clause ? So that I won't use any JOIN or multiple tables.

Comment: I'd fix it in two steps. Start with the cte's, only one is needed. Do `sum(when status = 'completed' then status end) as Denom` etc.

Comment: You don't need a CTE at all. You just need a case statement to make the numerator 1 or 0 depending on the status, something like this: `CASE WHEN Status LIKE 'cancelled%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as numerator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as denom,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num,
       AVG(CASE WHEN status <> 'completed' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as cancel_rate
FROM trips 
GROUP BY request_at;
```

Note that calculation for the `cancel_rate`.  This is simpler to do using `AVG()` rather than dividing the two values.  The use of `1.0`is because SQL Server does integer arithmetic, so `1 / 2` is 0 rather than 0.5.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `1.0` part. I did try similar thing but I was getting 0 as result which is why I took current approach !

Comment: You have one `)` too many in your formular and `AVG` does not calculate the same as `num/denom`.

Comment: @cars10 That is a typo I suppose. Removing it works well

Comment: And, of course, `AVG()` *does* deliver the correct result, as required (and explained) by OP ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit late again, but here is another variation (edited):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE LEFT(status,9) WHEN 'cancelled' THEN 1. ELSE 0 END)
      /COUNT(*) cancellation_rate,
       request_at 
FROM trips GROUP BY request_at ORDER BY request_at
```

Comment: Cancelration rate for 2013-10-01 is coming out to be 1 with your code

Comment: Well, the way I see it: all the completed reservations on that date were cancelled, so 1.0 would be the right value.

Comment: For 2013-10-01, there were 4 total rides, out of which 2 were completed and other two were cancelled. Hence 0.5 is the cancellation rate. :)

Comment: Ok, misunderstanding on my part. I took the first "completed" to mean an initial reservation. In that case my approach does not work.